# Replies to "nice to meet you"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can anyone help me to get the solution for the question below?

If someone tells me "nice to meet you" and I think it was a nice meeting,
what should I reply?.

Comment: Don't forget: Look forward to **chatting/speaking/seeing you** again

Comment: It's not clear if you are asking one question or two.

Answer (score 5):

You can reply:

> Nice to meet you, too!

or, shortened, "You, too!"

Other common expressions are:

- > My pleasure!
- > Same here!
- > Likewise.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to reply to *Nice to meet you,*

1. Thanks. It was nice to meet you, too

If you are also asking how to reply to, *It was a nice meeting,*

2. Yes it was. I'm glad you enjoyed it.